# How to change value of existing integer in the registry

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to change the value of an existing integer in the registry (for example, `EnableLUA`, which is located in `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System`) from 0 to 1. I know how to create a new integer value, but not how to edit an existing value.

I tried this code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR EnableLua = "EnableLUA";
    DWORD forLua = 1;
    RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System", &hKey);
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, EnableLua, 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)forLua, (DWORD)sizeof(forLua));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
A:\dev\secret++\SeriesOfExperiments\test_g_1.cpp:20:54: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   RegSetValueEx(hKey, SecureDesktop, 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)forLua, (DWORD)sizeof(forBehaviourAndSecure));
```

I know that the problem is in the `DWORD` for Lua, but I don't know how to change the integer value in the parameter.

This warning doesn't allow my program to work correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You missed an ampersand: `(PBYTE)&forLua`. `RegSetValueEx` takes a pointer to the data and size of the data.

Comment: You need to pass a *pointer* to the integer, not cast the integer to a pointer. The correct syntax would be `&forLua`. You also should be using "wide" strings. Add `#define UNICODE` and `#define _UNICODE` at the very top of your code file, then prefix your string literals with `L`.

Comment: Also, `RegOpenKey()` is very old, you should be using `RegOpenKeyEx()` instead.  And, be sure to check all functions for failures.